# jQuery: fade parent slowly, show / hide child instantly

Tags: jquery, parent, fade, children, instant

Is there a way to fade a parent element slowly and have a child element appear or disappear instantly?

I tried this, but it doesn't work..

**html**

```
<figure>
    <p>Foo Figure...</p>
    <figcaption>Bar Caption...</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('figure').hide();
$('figure').fadeIn({
    duration: 1000,
    start: function(){
         $(this).find('figcaption').show();
    }});
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/cpz3xoej/

Comment: You can hide child instantly while parent is shown but surely not show it instantly if parent is fading slowly. Meaning, you cannot get a child visible if parent is hidden

Answer (score 2):

You can not because fading animation is applied to parent which obviously includes child too.

You can use a workaround by applying the fadding effect to all the direct child, instead of the parent.

```
$('figure > *').hide();
$('figure > *').fadeIn({
    duration: 1000,
    start:function(){
        $(this).parent().find('figcaption').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: This only works assuming the figure itself is not hidden. The problem remains unsolved.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use "complete" method

```
$('figure').hide();
$('figcaption').hide()
$('figure').fadeIn({
duration: 1000,
complete:function(){
    $(this).find('figcaption').show();
}});
```

Comment: This does not make the child appear instantly. It makes the child pop in after the fade is complete. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/L7kzbdua/

Answer (score 0):

I slightly modified your code as below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('figure').hide();
    $('figure figcaption').hide();
    $('figure').fadeIn({
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function () {
            $(this).find('figcaption').fadeIn({duration: 400});
        }
    });
});
```

Which should work as expected

Comment: This does not make the child appear instantly. It makes the child pop in after the fade is complete.